# Cannot get multiple sql queries working for tree view PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, treeview

Ok I am trying to display this treeview here using mysql:

http://jeroenvdv.github.io/BootstrapTreeView/

I have a mysql db and i need to get the parent name text from a table, and then display all rows that belong to that parent_id.

like so:

```
table = 'groups'

|unique_id|name     |user_id |
| 1       | example | 1      |
| 2       | foo     | 3      |
| 3       | bar     | 2      |

table = 'entries'

|unique_id| entree_name     |user_id | group_id |
| 1       | apples          | 1      |     1    |
| 2       | oranges         | 3      |     2    |
| 3       | entree_example  | 2      |     3    |
```

Essentially I need the 'groups' to be parents, and the entries to be under the correct parents.

My problem with the code is that i only get the first result from the 'group' table and all rows under that table.

Here is my sloppy code, I am still learning.

```
<?php   

$user = $_SESSION['app']['user_id'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE user_id = '$user'";

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}
else
{


    echo '<div class="well">
            <ul class="list-group tree">
                <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" /><label class="tree-toggle tree-parent">Logged In User's Name<span class="icon-chevron-down"></span></label>
                    <ul class="list-group tree">';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $group = $row['id'];    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE group_id = '$group'";
?>
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" /><label class="tree-toggle tree-parent"><?php echo $row['name']; ?><span class="icon-chevron-down"></span></label>
        <ul class="list-group tree">                        
    <?php
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

echo '<li class="list-group-item"><label><input type="checkbox" />'; echo " " . $row['id']. " - " . $row['entree_name']; echo '</label></li>';

}
?>
    </ul>   
</li>
<?php
    }
    }
    ?>
                     </ul>                  
                </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is I only get ONE parent (the first one found by the query), and all entries under that parent group loaded into the tree. I know something that I am doing is wrong. I do not know what though. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You use the same variable names, $result and $row, for two separate queries that are nested. Because of this, you overwrite your 'groups' result variable (which you still need in order to process the next row from 'groups') with your result from the first 'entries' query here:

```
    <ul class="list-group tree">                        
<?php
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
```

You assign a new value to the $result variable, the result of your query on 'entries', overwriting the result you had from 'groups'. Because of that, after the first group, the while loop condition will fail and it will stop.

The same hold for the $row variable but in this case it doesn't lead to any problems. In general, I try not to reuse variable names unless I'm very sure they won't interfere. Giving variables more meaningful names, such as "$group_result", can help keep things organised too.